# mongodb - counting a non-null field using an index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, count, null, undefined

I'm answering my own question in the hope that it may help someone else. I am using mongodb (3.4), running a `count()` on an indexed string field, in a collection of 10m documents. I am looking for non-empty strings. Here are some performance metrics, where slow == collection_scan and fast == index_scan:

```
+----------------+-----------+
|   Constraint   |Performance|
+----------------+-----------+
| $exists(false) |   slow    |
| $exists(true)  |   slow    |
| $ne: ''        |   slow    |
| $eq: ''        |   fast    |
| $eq: null      |   slow    |
+----------------+-----------+
```

I think I mostly understand what is going on, namely:

**1. $exists(false)**

Non-existing fields will not enter the index, therefore mongodb must perform a collection scan in order to gather **all** documents for the `count()`.

**2. $exists(true)**

This is the one that got me. I thought it would be fast, but I was wrong. I think this is because if a field exists, and it's value is set to `undefined`, $exists() returns **true**. I can only assume that fields set to undefined do not enter the index either, and therefore again, mongodb must perform a collection scan in order to gather all documents for the count().

**3. $ne: ''**

I guess it's the same as $exists(false)

**4. $eq: ''**

This is a genuine string value, so it must exist in the index, therefore fast.

**4. $eq: null**

This is the other one that got me. This document helped a **lot** (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18653). In short, with the 2.6 release (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/#null-comparison-queries):

> null equality queries (i.e. field: null ) now match fields with values undefined

This query is slow. I can only assume that undefined fields are not indexed, and since null matches both, again, mongodb must perform a collection scan in order to gather all documents for the count().

So, what do?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

What I ended up doing, was using the regex `/^.+$/` to find non-empty strings. This uses the index and is super-fast. Equally important, I now try to avoid using `$exists()` and `$ne:`.

Thanks

Comment: and if you need to search for a field that is **explicitly** null (not with the value `undefined` nor a missing field), **using an index**, refer to (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-for-null-fields)


> If the query uses an index that is sparse, however, then the query will only match null values, **not** missing fields.

Comment: `/^.+$/` matches "anything" in a string That's what the "dot" means. `null` is not a string. And "negating" the match means it picks up "anything but a string". So it's not really the same thing now is it? You might want to go back and take a closer look at your tests.

Comment: So `{ "$gte": "" }` would actually outstrip an regex match every time. Uses an index of course as well.